# Clarifications about the method onLocationChanged

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to calculate the distance between my location and another location and write
it in a TextView at intervals of time.

I tried this:

```
private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG_LOG, "In onLocationChanged(...)");
        if(!mLatLngGpxList.isEmpty()) {
            Location loc = new Location("");
            loc.setLatitude(mLatLngGpxList.get(0).getLatitude());
            loc.setLongitude(mLatLngGpxList.get(0).getLongitude());
            float distance = mCurrentLocation.distanceTo(loc)/1000;
            distanceTextView.setText("Distance to Track: " + distance + " Km");
        }
    }
};
```

(I have this too..)

```
final LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, mLocationListener);
```

The distance chages only when the application is restarted and not in real time.

Maybe i should use a handler?

Comment: this answer will be helpful for your question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310126/get-the-distance-between-two-locations-in-android

Comment: The problem is not how to calculate the distance, but how to update the TextView in real time. I will try with a handler, called in onLocationChanged

Comment: You don't need a `Handler` for this as long as you've called `requestLocationUpdates()` on the main (UI) thread. Is `onLocationChanged()` getting called? Check your logcat.

Comment: Yes it's called. If i move in my house the distance don't change, but if i turn the phone it change.

Comment: I implemented the same thing with a handler and i obtain the same behavior. I want to cry.

Comment: Ok, i'm idiot. I forgot to call this istruction: mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation(); in onLocationChanged... T_T