# Calculate the distance between two positions using google map direction api android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to take the calculations between two points from Google distance api. There is any implementation source code link available to implement.

Documentation link is:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

Comment: how much have you understands from google documentation? you cannot just ask for source code here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. Hope this help :)

```
function getDistance(from, to){
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
        origins: [from],
        destinations: [to],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, function(response, status){callbackFunc();});
}

function callbackFunc(response, status){
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) 
    {
        console.log('Error was: ' + status);
    } 
    else
    {
        var from = response.originAddresses;
        var to = response.destinationAddresses;
        for (var i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
            var results = response.rows[i].elements;
            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                console.log(results[j].distance.value);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Javascript. Isn't the context of the question Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the great circle distance which is :

> the shortest distance between two points on the surface of a sphere

it allows you to calculate the distance between to lat/long point return by the API.

Here is a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) to the wikipedia page with the formula.

You will also find some implementation from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049612/calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310126/get-the-distance-between-two-locations-in-android)